# jquery onchange() - how to put a variable in quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I am building an HTML line in jQuery to append to a table in the HTML and want to capture when the input value changes. I am trying to pass a variable `obj.attNewChum` in the `onchange` attibute as follows:

```
contents = contents + "<input type='text' id='" + obj.cdId + "' name='" + obj.cdId + "' value='" + attMeeting + "' onchange='attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, "+obj.attNewChum+")'>";
```

However, this gives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: N is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Attendance.html:1)

attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, N)
```

The variable `obj.attNewChum` does contain the value `N`.

I have tried putting the variable in quotes:

```
contents = contents + "<input type='text' id='" + obj.cdId + "' name='" + obj.cdId + "' value='" + attMeeting + "' onchange='attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, "+"\"'obj.attNewChum'\""+")'>";
```

And that gives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: `console.log(obj);` could give you an idea what actually happens. (Should be added to your question as well in order to know what we are speaking about.)

Comment: convert double quotes into single quotes and single to double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as follows

```
 contents = contents +'<input type="text" id="'+obj.cdId+'" name="'+obj.cdId+'" value="'+attMeeting+'" onchange="attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, \''+obj.attNewChum+'\'")">';
```

Comment: A small correction at the end: contents = contents +'<input type="text" id="'+obj.cdId+'" name="'+obj.cdId+'" value="'+attMeeting+'" onchange="attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, \''+obj.attNewChum+'\')">';   Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative would be to attach the listener properly using Javascript instead, without using inline handlers, that way you don't have to deal with any escaping issues:

```
const input = $("<input>")
  .prop({
    id: obj.cdId,
    name:  obj.cdId,
    value: attMeeting
  });
input.on('change', function() {
  attendanceUpdateFunction(this.id, this.value, obj.attNewChum);
});
```

Note that this results in the `input` being a jQuery object rather than a string, so rather than concatenating the new HTML, you would want to `.append` the new element.

If, by chance, you're just using the `id` to try to pass the `obj.cdId` to `attendanceUpdateFunction`, you might consider removing the `id` entirely and just use the plain reference to `cdId`:

```
const input = $("<input>")
  .prop({
    name:  obj.cdId,
    value: attMeeting
  });
input.on('change', () => {
  attendanceUpdateFunction(obj.cdId, input.val(), obj.attNewChum);
});
```